# Using sssd on a diskless PXE clients

Tags: pxe, sssd

Does Ubuntu have an equivalent of `rwtab`?

I am attempting to get `sssd` to run on a read-only nfsroot. I have bypassed the logging failure with a systemd dropin file, but have yet to find an desirable way to start sssd.

```
[sssd] [ldb] (0x0020): Unable to open tdb '/var/lib/sss/db/config.ldb': Read-only filesystem
```

I can mount a `tmpfs` on `/var/lib/sss/` and copy the underlying files, but I am looking for a more officially supported option.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the non-variabled paths, there are probably other things wrong with this set of scripts.
This is **not** a proper recreation of how RHEL implements rwtab.

`/etc/systemd/system/rwtab.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Configure read-only root support
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=shutdown.target
Before=shutdown.target emergency.service emergency.target systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service local-fs.target systemd-random-seed.service
After=systemd-remount-fs.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/rwtab.sh
Type=oneshot
TimeoutSec=0
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target
```

`/usr/local/sbin/rwtab.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

mount -n -t tmpfs none
mkdir -p /tmp/rwtab/ro
mkdir -p /tmp/rwtab/rw
mount --bind --make-private / /tmp/rwtab/ro
mount -n -t tmpfs none /tmp/rwtab/rw
for path in $(sort /etc/rwtab); do
    mkdir -p /tmp/rwtab/rw/${path%/*}
    #rsync -a /tmp/rwtab/ro/$path/ /tmp/rwtab/rw/$path
    #mount --bind /tmp/rwtab/rw/$path $path
    cp -av /tmp/rwtab/ro/$path/ /tmp/rwtab/rw/${path%/*}
    mount -v --bind /tmp/rwtab/rw/$path $path
done
umount /tmp/rwtab/*
find /tmp/rwtab -xdev -empty -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

I was apparently looking for the package `overlayroot`.